# Material: Trying to style the form fields of a Mat-Card

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm new to UI development and don't have deep knowledge of css. I've been googling examples to style a login page using Angular Material. I'm trying to get the form fields to expand the width of the card (minus the padding), but not having any luck.

Can someone tell me what my form fields should look like? Also, I see that a lot of the styles have "example-" in their name. Are these to be defined in my css?

Here's my stylesheet:

```
.example-icon {
  padding: 0 14px;
}    
.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}    
.example-card {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}    
.example-header-image {
  background-image: image("./assets/logo.png");
  background-size: cover;
}    
.main-div {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And the html page:

```
<div class="main-div">
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <!--<div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>-->
      <img mat-card-avatar src="./assets/logo.png">
      <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form class="example-form">
        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" name="password" required>
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create style class in your .css file, which is used in template.

```css
.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

You dont need do use prefix example for your style classes, but dont forget to rename them both in template(.html file) and .css file.